# NancyFX error when doing per-route authentication in async route handler

Tags: c#, authentication, asynchronous, nancy

When I try to handle a route asynchronously and within that route I do the authentication, Nancy throws a `RouteExecutionEarlyExitException` and then the status code 500 (Internal Server Error) is returned instead of 401 (Unauthorized).

My route handler looks roughly like this:

```
Get["route/to/private/stuff", true] = async (args, ct) =>
{
    this.RequiresAuthentication()
    // process request
}
```

I followed the guidelines [here](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Stateless-Authentication) to configure stateless authentication.

It works as expected (throws exception internally, but returns 401) when my route handler looks like this:

```
Get["route/to/private/stuff"] = args =>
{
    this.RequiresAuthentication()
    // process request
}
```

How do I get Nancy to return 401 in an async route handler with per-route authentication?
I'm using Nancy 1.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I got it. Unfortunately I provided too little information.
I wasn't quite honest of how I process the request. Nancy fails with a 500 instead of a 401 when the `RouteExecutionEarlyExitException` is thrown synchronously, like here:

```
Get["/", true] = (args, ct) =>
{
    this.RequiresAuthentication();
    return Task.FromResult((object) "Hello World!");
};
```

AFAIK that wouldn't happen when Nancy used `await` when invoking the route handler (i.e. `await handler(args, ct)`) but it can happen when the handler is invoked synchronously (i.e. `handler(args, ct).ContinueWith(...)`).
And [it seems](http://sourcebrowser.io/Browse/NancyFx/Nancy/src/Nancy/Routing/DefaultRouteInvoker.cs#36) as Nancy uses the latter approach.

So the solution is to either stick with the `async` modifier or ensure that exceptions are only thrown asynchronously (e.g. within `Task.Run`).